# WinMain vs. main (C++)

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm fairly new to C++, but have done some .NET programming before.

What is the difference between `main(...)` and `WinMain(...)`, I wrote a program earlier with `main(...)` and was able to call Win32 functions just fine like I am with `WinMain(...)`, so this leads me to ask "where would it be best to use one over the other, or does it even make a difference?"

Comment: Broadly speaking, `WinMain()` is for GUI applications, `main()` is for console applications.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Talking about the Microsoft toolchain, conventionally, Win32 *graphical* applications have always started with `WinMain`, while `main` is used for *console* applications.

The difference between the two kinds of applications actually boils down (mostly) to a single setting in the executable, and is not in *capability* - a GUI application can create a console, and a console application can create a window - but in the behavior of the loader: for an exe marked as GUI the loader won't allocate any console, while a console exe will attach to the parent's console or create a new one if there isn't one.

For the entrypoint name, it is all just a matter of linker/CRT defaults: the "real" entry point of the executable is just an offset into the final executable, that points to a function that takes no parameters. It's the CRT that does its stuff, determines the parameters and then calls "your" entrypoint, so, in line of principle, they both could work exactly the same way.

The point is, the name/signature of the default entrypoint that the CRT looks for depends from the type of application you are building; if the compiler and linker are set to build a console application, they will look for a `main` (or `wmain` or `_tmain`, depending on Unicode settings), for a GUI application they use `WinMain`, and `DllMain` for a dll.

---

So:

- use `WinMain` if you are building a GUI (=no console created for it at startup) application;
- `main` for a console application;
- `DllMain` for a dll.

Again, this all isn't written in stone (and there are ways to start a GUI application from a standard `main`), but "when in Rome, do as the Romans do" - i.e. it's usually best to follow the uses of the platform to avoid confusing other developers and going through untested/unsupported compiler settings just to change the signature of the entrypoint.

Comment: `...the "real" entry point of the executable is just an offset into the final executable, that points to a function that takes no parameters.` Worth mentioning that that function is typically called `_start`.

Comment: @ColeJohnson: surely on Linux (I've written several), but is that true also on Win32?

Comment: On Windows, it’s generally called `mainCRTStartup`

Answer (score 2):

`WinMain()` is Windows specific entry point to a Windows-based graphical application (you have windows stuff). `main()` is a standard C++ entry point (in Windows, it's a console based application)...

That said, you can use GUI stuff in console applications and allocate console in GUI applications.

I would recommend reading on [consoles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682528%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [GUI applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633559%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in Windows on MSDN.

Comment: This is by tradition only, there's nothing stopping a console-based app from creating a GUI and there's nothing stopping a GUI app from creating a console (as mentioned in Matteo Italia's answer).

Comment: @dreamlax And I quote: "_That said, you can use GUI stuff in console applications and allocate console in GUI applications._"