# Entry point function in Mongoose Web Server source code

Tags: c, mongoose-web-server

I'm a web developer, trying to learn more about C programming. My C training is purely academic, so i thought i'd start with reading some source code on Github.
My project of choice was https://github.com/cesanta/mongoose - Mongoose Web Server, as i used it on several occasions.

Browsing through the source (mongoose.c), i noticed there is no 'main' function. I can't figure out what is the first function that is called.

So, my questions are:
1. Isn't there always a main function in C programs?
2. If not, how do i figure out what is the first function that is called?

Comment: There are plenty of examples on your link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is always an entry point to any *program*, but software *libraries* generally do not have entry points. In terms of whether the entry point is always called `main`, you can look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18709447/391161).

`mongoose.c` is the source code for a **library**, so there is no `main` function.

The `main` functions are all in the clients of that library, which are available under [examples](https://github.com/cesanta/mongoose/tree/master/examples).