# Error observed in my first C language 'Hello World' program

Tags: c

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAk4y.jpg)

Installed VS Code then installed MinGW64 for Windows 10 then setup environment variables then opened VS Code where created new folder by name 'C Tutorial' therein a new file as 'Hello.c' and typed basic Hello World program.
Was expecting 'Hello World' text to be printed on terminal instead received some error which I cannot interpret as of now.

Comment: Maybe try `#include <windows.h>` ???

Comment: You actually have two related errors, the first in white text is from the link saying that it failed, and did not make an executable.  The second in red text is from powershell saying that it can not find the executable to run (which would have been made had the link ran correctly).  For the first, windows has a number of subsystems - GUI, console, Driver, etc  (each has its own entry point) you need to tell the compiler what subsystem that you are using, so for mingw64 add '-mconsole' to your command line.  Once you fix the first error, the second error should go away.

Comment: @Shreyas Deshpande I'm working on an answer for you, but I wanted to ask you 2 questions.  Do you have prior programming experience and what is your learning resource?  Were you following along to a YouTube video?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use forward slash to call the program.
I.e `./a.exe`

Add *void* to the main function like this.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("Hello World");
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Apparently his compiler (more properly his linker) did not even produce the executable.

Comment: Thanks,  It's now working somehow with the forward slash and both errors are gone instead implicit declaration of print function is now displayed, any idea?

Answer (score 1):

There are several possible issues that you may be running into.  However, I want to start with a word of caution.  I, personally, really enjoy programming, C especially, and find it very comfortable.  However, you need to make sure as a programmer, especially a C programmer, that you are paying very close attention to every detail.  You seem to be new to programming so I apologize if this is an overly complex answer.  Also, have put **Definition** and **Declaration** in bold for special attention since I find it easy to mix them up.  They are not the same thing.  See this question for more information:

[What is the difference between a definition and a declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration)

---

The first thing that I want to say is that VSCode is showing your source "Hello.c" file as unsaved.  I don't know if the contents shown in your screenshot truly match that which was used by your build commands.

The next thing is that your terminal output shows 2 errors.  The first is from your build command:

```
gcc Hello.c
```

This command will attempt to both compile and then link your code into an executable program.  Since you did not specify an output name, it will default to "a.exe" on Windows.  On other platforms the default is usually "a.out".  If you pass the `-c` option to gcc, it will attempt to only compile, not link.  Compilation and linking are 2 distinct steps.  Compilation takes the input and runs the preprocessor, then attempts to parse and convert your source code into machine code.  However, your code can refer to symbols outside of that "compilation unit".  Symbols usually refer to things like functions and global variables.  Before your program can be run, it must be linked against any outside dependencies to resolve the symbols references.  For example, you are calling a function *printf()* to print "Hello World".  You do not include the **definition** of the function *printf()* anywhere in your source code.  It is part of the C library.  During linking, the gcc will default to attempting to link against the C library and there it will be able to resolve your reference to the *printf()* function.  The only function you, in your Hello World program, provide a **definition** for is the function *main()*.

The good news is that compilation succeeded.  Compilation is the step where syntax errors and the like will be reported by the compiler.  So internally, gcc was able to compile and generate the machine code for your *main()* function.  The bad news is that the linking failed.  Linking errors are harder to parse, especially for a beginner.  In your case it was attempting to resolve a reference to a symbol called *WinMain*.  This has to do with some Windows specific stuff that I am not completely familiar with.  However, before I can explain further I need to go on another tangent.

When a program starts executing the operating system starts at a location referred to a the program entry point.  This is the memory address of some machine instruction within the binary machine code of a fully built program.  While as a new C programmer, you may think of the *main()* function as the start, it is not actually the entry point of the program (At least not usually or by default).

If it is not clear by now, gcc actually does a lot of magic behind the scenes and this can create problems for programs that have special needs or use cases, such as firmware.  Often in such cases, special CFLAGS need to be used to carefully control what gcc is actually doing.

One of the things that gcc does by default during linking is to link-in a precompiled object file.  The exact one depends on the type of build and this may be different on different plaforms, but usually on Linux it is some file called "crt1.o".  This file contains the true entry point of the program, usually referred to by the symbol *_start*.  It initializes the C Library sets up special CPU registers, such as global pointers, etc..., and then finally calls the function *main().*  Under the typical Linux build defaults, this would get automatically linked-in.

So the oversimplified call graph of your Hello World program is:

1. _start - crtn.o
2. main - your provided source code
3. printf - the C library

This is again oversimplified because there are likely many calls being made within crtn.o before *your()* main function and within the *printf()* function of the C library.  Additionally, that _start is not really a function as it is usually implemented with hand Assembly, it's not really following a calling ABI, it won't return because there is no where for it to go, etc...

The point, however, is that your *main()* function itself is represented as a symbol within the linking process that the linker is trying to resolve between your source code and suppled pre-compiled initialization code.

This brings me to the Windows funniness.  By convention on Windows, a program may have one of 2 different "main" functions (Note the quotes, not italics).  If it is console application, it will attempt to start by calling *main()*.  If it is a GUI application it will attempt to start by calling *WinMain()*.  The main difference is that a GUI application will generally not attempt to spawn or attach a console.  You can, of course, create a GUI within a console application and spawn a terminal within a GUI application.  I have been working a GUI program, using the WinMain function but also keeping the Attach Console behavior so I can easily use print statement debugging.  I want to also make you aware that the function prototypes for *main()* and *WinMain()* are different and case-sensitive.

There is another question about the exact differences between *WinMain()* and *main()* here if you want to read more:
[WinMain vs. main (C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18709403/winmain-vs-main-c)

As a bit of an aside, *WinMain()* does not contain the traditional argc and argv parameters.  However, Windows has some hidden global symbols for them with the names __argc and __argv.  You can access them using their normal types if you are trying to write a cross-platform GUI program uses them.  If you don't know what I mean in this paragraph, don't worry.  By the time you need this, you'll understand.

I want to mention that it looks like you are using an older version of the MinGW GNU GCC Windows port.  You should be aware that the project was forked years ago into the MinGW-w64 project.  Your older compiler may have some behavior quirks that I am unable to replicate on the versions I am using.

Anyway, the Windows port of GCC has the command line options `-mwindows` and `-mconsole`.  It is likely that your older version of GCC is defaulting to `-mwindows` and you need to specify `-mconsole` to get it to try to link against *main* instead of *WinMain*.  The version of GCC that I have didn't really seem to have this issue, however.  It is also possible that your PATH variables were not setup correctly and are causing GCC to look for the wrong object files during the link.  Keep in mind, you may have to logout and login (Not lock/switch user) or even restart your computer for PATH changes to completely take effect.

Since your linking failed, your build failed and no program, "a.exe", was created.  That is the reason for your second error message in the terminal.  That is the general command not found error of Window PowerShell.  Yes, it's very wordy.

Another possible quirk of your old complier is what appears to be mangled syntax.  While this worked fine for me, your complier may be choking on the syntax of your first line:

```
# include<stdio.h>
```

Normal syntax for this is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

Lines that start with # are processed by the preprocessor.  An #include statement basically has the effect of replacing itself with the contents the file it is including.  However, I believe the # symbol is treated by the complier itself (after the preprocessing is done) as a line comment.  If you run gcc in preprocess only mode with the command flag `-E`, you will see what I mean.  You mentioned in your comments that your earlier error is now gone and that you are now getting an implicit function **declaration** error.  This means that you have not told the compiler about a function before you have starting using it.  The **declaration** of the *printf()* function is part of the "stdio.h" header file.  I suspect the problem above was introduced with the unsaved changes in your VSCode editor and that after your original post, you saved the file, creating that problem.  I suspect your older version of GCC is treating that line as a line comment due to the bad syntax.
Again, make sure you are paying attention to the details.

If you had an earlier version of GCC on your computer, make sure that your changes to the PATH take precedence.  Check the version of gcc with the command:

```
gcc --version
```

---

A few other notes.

You are probably aware, but the `main()` function has some parameters that are passed to it, such as argc, argv, and envp.  It doesn't really hurt anything to not include them if you aren't going to use any of them, but it is important to fill it out completely if you intend to use any of them.

Also, your print statements don't include a new line.  This could be intentional.  Maybe you don't want a new line.  However, I expect this was unintentional.  In my testing, PowerShell seems to have some magic where it will add a new line even if you don't.  However, you will begin to see the problem if you write 2 consecutive lines containing:

```
printf("Hello World");
```

On Linux, when BASH returns, it won't append a new line and therefore, your terminal prompt will be appended to the end of the last line your printed.  The print code including the new line is:

```
printf("Hello World\n");
```

The character `\` is called a delimiter.  It allows you to have create special meaning within otherwise plain text.  For example if you wanted to put the character " in the string, you would not want to have the C language treat that character as the end of the string.  So you could embed 3 double quote characters into your string like this:

```
printf("He\"llo W\"\"orld");
```

You can also delimit the delimiter to write backslashes into your string with `\\`.  The `\n` has the meaning of the ASCII character 10 (New Line).  You can look it up on an ASCII Table if you are curious.  This is one of the things I like about C, very little to no magic.  You get exactly what you say.  It is very literal, down to needing to specify your own line endings.

Lastly, and this is not really an issue in modern times, more just a historical quirk of really old parsers.  I don't believe it is legal C to not end the file with an empty line.  Your file ends on line 6, but line 6 is not empty.  Again, it's more of a funny quirk of the language specification.  I don't know of any compiler that actually will complain or be unable to parse C source code without an empty last line.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how it got resolved but if someone knows please explain for future references. Here's my (rookie) explanation:

Used forward slash / for **./a.exe** as per a comment here and then on new terminal pressed 'run' button slightly towards top right it then asked something complex but I pressed on gcc option which popped up on search bar, which brought in 'tasks.json' file, which then compiled code successfully.
However, 'implicit declaration for printf function' issue arose, again used run button and same process automatically repeated and totally fixed it

Thanks for support.